# Update to React 0.60.4 breaks Android build (error cannot find symbol)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I have recently updated to `React Native@0.60.4`.

The app compiles and works fine on iOS and xcode. However, when I try and run the new android code I face the following error:

```sh
/redacted/MainApplication.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
                         ^
  symbol:   class PackageList
  location: package com.facebook.react
/redacted/MainApplication.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
                                        ^
  symbol: class PackageList
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

This is my MainApplication.java

```java
package com.my.app;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutorFactory;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptExecutorFactory;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;

import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

`$ npx react-native info` dump

```sh
System:
    OS: macOS 10.14.5
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3615QM CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Memory: 288.14 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.4.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.17.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 12.4, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.4, watchOS 5.3
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.6156.11.34.5692245
    Xcode: 10.3/10G8 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6
    react-native: 0.60.4 => 0.60.4
```

Comment: looks like the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56951512/react-native-cannot-find-symbol-after-upgrade-to-0-60/56972260

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-Native cannot find symbol after upgrade to 0.60](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56951512/react-native-cannot-find-symbol-after-upgrade-to-0-60)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was missing the new stuff inside `android/app/build.gradle` when I used https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.8&to=0.60.4

The `android/app/build.gradle` file was closed and I missed it