# React-Native: Task in Azure Pipelines fail but in local it does not

Tags: react-native, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm having a weird problem with Azure Pipelines that is doing our CI to our React-Native project and locally I run exactly the same task that it is running on the pipelines, on the pipelines Android build fails but locally it’s just fine.

In local (brief):

```
[12:53:07]: ▸ > Task :react-native-freshchat-sdk:verifyReleaseResources
[12:53:07]: ▸ > Task :react-native-freshchat-sdk:assembleRelease
[12:53:07]: ▸ > Task :react-native-localize:mergeReleaseJavaResource
[12:53:07]: ▸ > Task :react-native-localize:syncReleaseLibJars
[12:53:07]: ▸ > Task :react-native-localize:bundleReleaseAar
[12:53:07]: ▸ > Task :react-native-localize:verifyReleaseResources
[12:53:07]: ▸ > Task :react-native-localize:assembleRelease
[12:53:07]: ▸ > Task :react-native-reanimated:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
[12:53:08]: ▸ > Task :react-native-push-notification:mergeReleaseResources
[12:53:08]: ▸ > Task :react-native-reanimated:extractReleaseAnnotations
[12:53:08]: ▸ > Task :react-native-reanimated:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[12:53:08]: ▸ > Task :react-native-reanimated:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[12:53:08]: ▸ > Task :react-native-reanimated:compileReleaseSources
[12:53:08]: ▸ > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
[12:53:08]: ▸ > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:extractReleaseAnnotations
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-reanimated:mergeReleaseResources
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileReleaseSources
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-push-notification:verifyReleaseResources
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-push-notification:assembleRelease
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-reanimated:mergeReleaseJavaResource
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-reanimated:syncReleaseLibJars
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-reanimated:bundleReleaseAar
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:mergeReleaseJavaResource
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:syncReleaseLibJars
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:bundleReleaseAar
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-screens:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:mergeReleaseResources
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-screens:extractReleaseAnnotations
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-screens:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-screens:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-reanimated:verifyReleaseResources
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-reanimated:assembleRelease
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-screens:compileReleaseSources
[12:53:09]: ▸ > Task :react-native-screens:mergeReleaseJavaResource
[12:53:10]: ▸ > Task :react-native-screens:syncReleaseLibJars
[12:53:10]: ▸ > Task :react-native-screens:bundleReleaseAar
[12:53:10]: ▸ > Task :react-native-spinkit:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
[12:53:11]: ▸ > Task :react-native-screens:mergeReleaseResources
[12:53:11]: ▸ > Task :react-native-spinkit:extractReleaseAnnotations
[12:53:11]: ▸ > Task :react-native-spinkit:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[12:53:11]: ▸ > Task :react-native-spinkit:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[12:53:11]: ▸ > Task :react-native-spinkit:compileReleaseSources
[12:53:12]: ▸ > Task :react-native-spinkit:mergeReleaseResources
[12:53:12]: ▸ > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:verifyReleaseResources
[12:53:12]: ▸ > Task :react-native-safe-area-context:assembleRelease
[12:53:12]: ▸ > Task :react-native-splash-screen:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
[12:53:12]: ▸ > Task :react-native-splash-screen:extractReleaseAnnotations
[12:53:12]: ▸ > Task :react-native-splash-screen:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[12:53:12]: ▸ > Task :react-native-splash-screen:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[12:53:12]: ▸ > Task :react-native-splash-screen:compileReleaseSources
[12:53:12]: ▸ > Task :react-native-spinkit:mergeReleaseJavaResource
[12:53:12]: ▸ > Task :react-native-spinkit:syncReleaseLibJars
[12:53:12]: ▸ > Task :react-native-spinkit:bundleReleaseAar
[12:53:12]: ▸ > Task :react-native-splash-screen:mergeReleaseJavaResource
[12:53:12]: ▸ > Task :react-native-splash-screen:syncReleaseLibJars
[12:53:12]: ▸ > Task :react-native-splash-screen:bundleReleaseAar
[12:53:12]: ▸ > Task :react-native-svg:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
[12:53:13]: ▸ > Task :react-native-splash-screen:mergeReleaseResources
[12:53:13]: ▸ > Task :react-native-svg:extractReleaseAnnotations
[12:53:13]: ▸ > Task :react-native-svg:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[12:53:13]: ▸ > Task :react-native-svg:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[12:53:13]: ▸ > Task :react-native-spinkit:verifyReleaseResources
[12:53:13]: ▸ > Task :react-native-spinkit:assembleRelease
[12:53:13]: ▸ > Task :react-native-svg:compileReleaseSources
[12:53:13]: ▸ > Task :react-native-screens:verifyReleaseResources
[12:53:13]: ▸ > Task :react-native-screens:assembleRelease
[12:53:13]: ▸ > Task :react-native-svg:mergeReleaseJavaResource
[12:53:13]: ▸ > Task :react-native-svg:syncReleaseLibJars
[12:53:13]: ▸ > Task :react-native-svg:bundleReleaseAar
[12:53:13]: ▸ > Task :react-native-vector-icons:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
[12:53:13]: ▸ > Task :react-native-svg:mergeReleaseResources
[12:53:13]: ▸ > Task :react-native-splash-screen:verifyReleaseResources
[12:53:13]: ▸ > Task :react-native-splash-screen:assembleRelease
[12:53:14]: ▸ > Task :react-native-vector-icons:extractReleaseAnnotations
[12:53:14]: ▸ > Task :react-native-vector-icons:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[12:53:14]: ▸ > Task :react-native-vector-icons:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[12:53:14]: ▸ > Task :react-native-vector-icons:compileReleaseSources
[12:53:14]: ▸ > Task :react-native-vector-icons:mergeReleaseResources
[12:53:14]: ▸ > Task :react-native-webview:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
[12:53:14]: ▸ > Task :react-native-webview:extractReleaseAnnotations
[12:53:14]: ▸ > Task :react-native-webview:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[12:53:14]: ▸ > Task :react-native-webview:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[12:53:14]: ▸ > Task :react-native-webview:compileReleaseSources
[12:53:14]: ▸ > Task :react-native-svg:verifyReleaseResources
[12:53:14]: ▸ > Task :react-native-svg:assembleRelease
[12:53:14]: ▸ > Task :react-native-vector-icons:mergeReleaseJavaResource
[12:53:14]: ▸ > Task :react-native-vector-icons:syncReleaseLibJars
[12:53:14]: ▸ > Task :react-native-vector-icons:bundleReleaseAar
[12:53:15]: ▸ > Task :react-native-webview:mergeReleaseResources
[12:53:15]: ▸ > Task :react-native-vector-icons:verifyReleaseResources
[12:53:15]: ▸ > Task :react-native-vector-icons:assembleRelease
[12:53:15]: ▸ > Task :react-native-webview:mergeReleaseJavaResource
[12:53:15]: ▸ > Task :react-native-webview:syncReleaseLibJars
[12:53:15]: ▸ > Task :react-native-webview:bundleReleaseAar
[12:53:16]: ▸ > Task :react-native-webview:verifyReleaseResources
[12:53:16]: ▸ > Task :react-native-webview:assembleRelease
[12:53:16]: ▸ Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[12:53:16]: ▸ Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[12:53:16]: ▸ See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[12:53:16]: ▸ BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 26s
[12:53:16]: ▸ 653 actionable tasks: 592 executed, 61 up-to-date
[12:53:16]: Cruising back to lane 'android dev' 

+------+------------------------------+-------------+
|                 fastlane summary                  |
+------+------------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                       | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform             | 0           |
| 2    | Switch to android build lane | 0           |
| 3    | clean assembleRelease        | 147         |
+------+------------------------------+-------------+

[12:53:16]: fastlane.tools finished successfully 
✨  Done in 151.87s.
```

Error in pipelines:

```
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4035490Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m> Task :react-native-freshchat-sdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4136050Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-freshchat-sdk/android/src/main/java/com/freshchat/consumer/sdk/react/RNFreshchatSdkPackage.java:3: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4238350Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mimport android.support.annotation.NonNull;[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4300260Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m^[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4330640Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-freshchat-sdk/android/src/main/java/com/freshchat/consumer/sdk/react/StringUtils.java:3: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4349530Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mimport android.support.annotation.NonNull;[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4350630Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m^[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4352200Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-freshchat-sdk/android/src/main/java/com/freshchat/consumer/sdk/react/RNFreshchatSdk.java:9: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4353610Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mimport android.support.annotation.NonNull;[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4354570Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m^[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4356000Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-freshchat-sdk/android/src/main/java/com/freshchat/consumer/sdk/react/RNFreshchatSdk.java:10: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4357420Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mimport android.support.annotation.Nullable;[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4358290Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m^[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4359690Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-freshchat-sdk/android/src/main/java/com/freshchat/consumer/sdk/react/RNFreshchatSdk.java:11: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4361190Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mimport android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4362090Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m^[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4363450Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-freshchat-sdk/android/src/main/java/com/freshchat/consumer/sdk/react/RNFreshchatSdkPackage.java:22: error: cannot find symbol[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4365030Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mpublic List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(@NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4366010Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m^[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4367030Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35msymbol:   class NonNull[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4368000Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mlocation: class RNFreshchatSdkPackage[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4369480Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-freshchat-sdk/android/src/main/java/com/freshchat/consumer/sdk/react/RNFreshchatSdkPackage.java:27: error: cannot find symbol[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4371350Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mpublic List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(@NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4518060Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mpublic void identifyUser(@NonNull String externalId, @NonNull String restoreId, @Nullable final Callback errorCallback) {[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4519090Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m^[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4519920Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35msymbol:   class Nullable[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4520840Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mlocation: class RNFreshchatSdk[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4522140Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-freshchat-sdk/android/src/main/java/com/freshchat/consumer/sdk/react/RNFreshchatSdk.java:436: error: cannot find symbol[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4523490Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mpublic void restoreUser(@NonNull String jwt, @Nullable final Callback errorCallback) {[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4524530Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m^[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4526850Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35msymbol:   class NonNull[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4528010Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mlocation: class RNFreshchatSdk[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4529450Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-freshchat-sdk/android/src/main/java/com/freshchat/consumer/sdk/react/RNFreshchatSdk.java:436: error: cannot find symbol[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4548550Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mpublic void restoreUser(@NonNull String jwt, @Nullable final Callback errorCallback) {[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4549630Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m^[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4550510Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35msymbol:   class Nullable[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4551430Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mlocation: class RNFreshchatSdk[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4552880Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-freshchat-sdk/android/src/main/java/com/freshchat/consumer/sdk/react/RNFreshchatSdk.java:445: error: cannot find symbol[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4554180Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mpublic void sendMessage(@NonNull ReadableMap readableMap) {[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4555070Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m^[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4555920Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35msymbol:   class NonNull[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4556820Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mlocation: class RNFreshchatSdk[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4558090Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-freshchat-sdk/android/src/main/java/com/freshchat/consumer/sdk/react/RNFreshchatSdk.java:460: error: cannot find symbol[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4559390Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mpublic void setPushRegistrationToken(@NonNull String token) {[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4560290Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m^[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4561110Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35msymbol:   class NonNull[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4562030Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mlocation: class RNFreshchatSdk[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4563310Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-freshchat-sdk/android/src/main/java/com/freshchat/consumer/sdk/react/RNFreshchatSdk.java:471: error: cannot find symbol[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4564640Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mpublic void setNotificationConfig(@NonNull ReadableMap readableMap) {[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4565550Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m^[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4566380Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35msymbol:   class NonNull[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4567290Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mlocation: class RNFreshchatSdk[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4569050Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-freshchat-sdk/android/src/main/java/com/freshchat/consumer/sdk/react/RNFreshchatSdk.java:604: error: cannot find symbol[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4570360Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mpublic void getUserIdTokenStatus(@NonNull final Callback callback) {[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4706040Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m^[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4706870Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35msymbol: class Nullable[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4707710Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m58 errors[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4708670Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:javaPreCompileRelease[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4709760Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:parseReleaseLocalResources[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4710870Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:processReleaseManifest[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4711990Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mFAILURE: Build failed with an exception.[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4712920Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m* What went wrong:[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4713990Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mExecution failed for task ':react-native-freshchat-sdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4715230Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4716160Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m* Try:[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4717340Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mRun with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4718540Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4719660Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mDeprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4720800Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mUse '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4721980Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mSee https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4723020Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35mBUILD FAILED in 1m 45s[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:44.4723990Z [18:51:44]: â–¸ [35m109 actionable tasks: 88 executed, 21 up-to-date[0m
2020-07-30T18:51:46.2174230Z +------------------+-------------+
2020-07-30T18:51:46.2175480Z |          [33mLane Context[0m          |
2020-07-30T18:51:46.2176470Z +------------------+-------------+
2020-07-30T18:51:46.2177270Z | DEFAULT_PLATFORM | ios         |
2020-07-30T18:51:46.2177750Z | PLATFORM_NAME    | android     |
2020-07-30T18:51:46.2178200Z | LANE_NAME        | android dev |
2020-07-30T18:51:46.2178960Z +------------------+-------------+
2020-07-30T18:51:46.2180060Z [18:51:46]: [31mExit status of command '/Users/runner/work/1/s/android/gradlew clean assembleRelease -p android/' was 1 instead of 0.
2020-07-30T18:51:46.2181300Z Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
2020-07-30T18:51:46.2182060Z ....................................................................................................................................
```

It's something with freshchat ... weird thing is that locally it goes just fine.

Heres the YAML file:

```
    pool:
  vmImage: "macos-latest"

steps:
- task: UseNode@1
  inputs:
    checkLatest: true

- task: YarnInstaller@2
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '1.x'
    checkLatest: true

- task: Yarn@2
  inputs:
    Arguments: install

- script: |
   if [ "${SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_TARGETBRANCH}" == "master" ]; then
       yarn run config-prod
   else
       yarn run config-dev
   fi
  displayName: '12 Factor'

- task: geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-yarn.yarn-task.Yarn@2
  displayName: 'Yarn lint'
  inputs:
    Arguments: lint

- script: |
   bundle update fastlane
  displayName: 'Update Fastlane'

- script: |
   gem install bundler:1.17.3
   bundle install
  displayName: 'Install GEM'

- task: geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-yarn.yarn-task.Yarn@2
  displayName: 'Yarn ios:install'
  inputs:
    Arguments: 'ios:install'

- task: geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-yarn.yarn-task.Yarn@2
  displayName: 'Yarn build-ios'
  inputs:
    Arguments: 'ios:dev'

- task: geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-yarn.yarn-task.Yarn@2
  displayName: 'Yarn build-android'
  inputs:
    Arguments: 'android:dev'
```

Any Ideas what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to be caused by this "`error: package android.support.annotation does not exist`". Please check if these threads help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57166876/update-to-react-0-60-4-breaks-android-build-error-cannot-find-symbol and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40380519/error-package-com-android-annotations-does-not-exist and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56951512/react-native-cannot-find-symbol-after-upgrade-to-0-60. Please also try use Microsoft hosted agent `macOS-10.14` or setup and use a self-hosted agent on your local machine to check if it has the same issue.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply! I tried all the solutions but no luck so far... I think it's gotta be with how the agent has android studio configured.

Comment: So, I recommend that you could setup a self-hosted agent (one the machine which you can build locally) and debug according using it. Generally, if you can run successfully with the self-hosted agent, then it will also work using the Microsoft Hosted agent with the same settings.

Comment: Thanks for your replies Andy I don't know how to do this but I will look into it.

Comment: You can refer to [Self-hosted macOS agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-osx?view=azure-devops) to setup and use the self-hosted agent.